# Describe all path-connected $3$ fold covers of $X=S^1 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, normal-subgroups, products, free-groups

> Describe all path-connected $3$ fold covers of $X=S^1 \vee \Bbb{R}P^2$ (please justify why your list is exhaustive). Which are regular (i.e. normal) and why?

I get that $X$ has a universal cover, hence the covers would be in one-to-one correspondence with subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$. Now, $\pi_1(X)=\Bbb{Z} * \Bbb{Z}_2$. So, I basically need to find the subgroups of $\Bbb{Z} * \Bbb{Z}_2$ of index $3$ and the normal covers would correspond to normal subgroups. But how do I find the normal subgroups of $\Bbb{Z} * \Bbb{Z}_2$? What is the general structure of subgroups of $\Bbb{Z} * \Bbb{Z}_2$ anyway?

Comment: $\pi_1(X)$ is not $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ but is the free product of the two groups, $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_2$. This follows from a Van Kampen argument.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman Yeah, right. That's a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p : E\rightarrow B$ be a 3 fold cover, where $B = S^1 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2$. Let $x\in B$ be the basepoint. As $p$ is a 3-fold cover, $|p^{-1}(x)| = 3$ and $\pi_1(B,x)$ induces a right action on the set $p^{-1}(x)$. If this action is transitive, then the covering space $E$ is connected.

So the question becomes, in how many ways can $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}_2$ act transitively on the set $\{1,2,3\}$. We may use the following presentation for our group:
$$\langle a,b | b^2 = e \rangle $$

Now we enumerate the possiblities of where the elements can map too.

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ $1*b = 1$, $2*b = 2$.

As $b$ has order 2, this forces the action of $b$ to be trivial. Now if $a$ was also trivial, the action would not be transitive, and the cover wouldn't be connected. Hence $1*a = 2$ or $1*a = 3$. Making this choice forces you to choose $a^2$ and $a^3$ as well, with $a^3 = id$.  Both of these actions determine homeomorphic covering spaces; the circle with three vertice, and at each vertex, a copy of $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ $1*b = 2$, $2*b = 1$.
Again, if $a$ acts trivially, the action can't be transitive. Now suppose $ 1*a = 1$, then $2*a = 3$ and $3*a = 2$. This corresponds (up to homeomorphism) to the covering space given by a 2-sphere with two vertices (say at the north and south pole). At the north pole, there is a single circle. at the south pole, two arcs, with opposite end points for both arcs residing in a copy of $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

$\textbf{Case 3:}$ Now if $a*1 = 2$ instead, then $a*2 =3$. If it didn't, then both $a$ and $b$ would leave the point $3$ fixed, and hence the action wouldn't be transitive. So, This covering space is given by a two sphere with two vertices, and a copy of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with a single vertex. The vertex on the $\mathbb{R}P^2$ corresponds to the point $3$ in our set. There are two arcs emminateing from this vertex and each arc terminates at a different pole of the 2-sphere. Finally, there an an arc connecting the two vertices of the two sphere.

Up to homeomorphism, these are the three different connected 3-fold covers of $S^1 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2$. To answer part two, try and draw the covers, then look for the ones which are symmetric.

Comment: $\text{Covering }(1):$ Take three copies of $\Bbb RP^2$ and a copy of $\Bbb S^1$. Add a copy of $\Bbb RP^2$ at the points $1, e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}, e^{i\frac{4\pi}{3}}$ of $\Bbb S^1$.

Comment: $\text{Covering }(2):$ Take a copy of $\Bbb S^2$ and a copy of $\Bbb RP^2$. Let $x\in \Bbb S^2$, and its class $[x]\in \Bbb RP^2$. Consider two arcs joining the points $[x],x$ and then add a copy of $\Bbb S^1$ at $-x\in\Bbb S^2$.

Comment: $\text{Covering }(3):$ Take a copy of $\Bbb S^2$ and a copy of $\Bbb RP^2$. Let $x\in \Bbb S^2$, and its class $[x]\in \Bbb RP^2$. Consider an arc joining $[x], x$; another arc joining $[x], -x$; yet another arc joining $x,-x$. The intersection of any two arcs can be either $x$ or $-x$ or $[x]$.

Comment: No, it's not the same action. The action I described above is how the whole fundamental group is acting on a single fiber. It's a different action than the deck transformations

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding. I deleted the last comment by mistake, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric?